# Outlook not refreshing deleted attachment and property set using C++ MAPI Add-in

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

I have Outlook Add-in developed in C++, MAPI using Visual Studio.

I have to add functionality for deleting attachment if it is blocked from my server side, for that, when user clicks on Send button of New Meeting I fetch the attachment using GetAttachmentTable(). And iterate thro all the attachments, and deleting the attachments which needs to be deleted as per my requirement.

For deleting I am using IMessage::DeleteAttach() passing the req parameter.
I check the return value (HRESULT) which is success.

Now when I check the meeting in Calendar, It shows all the attachment (along with deleted one). Actually it has deleted the attachment but somehow not refreshed it.

Once I restart the outlook, deleted attachment disappears and it shows only the undeleted attachments.

Any clue why it would have been behaving like that?

Used Outlook Object Model(OOM) but it's throwing exception at myattachments->Remove(1);

```
CLSID clsidOutlook;
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Outlook.Application", &clsidOutlook);
        
Olk::_ApplicationPtr pOlkApp;
hr = CoCreateInstance(clsidOutlook, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
Olk::IID__Application, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&(pOlkApp)));
Olk::_InspectorPtr pInsp = pOlkApp->ActiveInspector();
if (NULL == pInsp)
{
    LOG(_T("Failed to obtain Inspector"));
    return S_FALSE;
}

IDispatchPtr dispItem = pInsp->GetCurrentItem();
if (NULL == dispItem)
{
    LOG(_T("Failed to obtain Inspector"));
    return S_FALSE;
}
CComQIPtr<Olk::_AppointmentItem> spAppointmentItem = dispItem;

if (spAppointmentItem)
{
    auto myattachments = spAppointmentItem->Attachments;
    if (myattachments->Count > 0)
    {
        myattachments->Remove(1);       //Her it throws error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Application.ItemSend` event, keep in mind that you end up dealing with the `MeetignItem` object, not with the actual `AppointmentItem` object in the Calendar folder.

Still, if you want the UI to be refreshed, do use Outlook Object Model to delete the atatchment - there is absolutely no advantage using Extended MAPI for that.

Comment: Thanks @Dimtry Streblechenko for your answer. I tried to use OOM but it's not helping. I updated the same code snippet in above question jut now. Also in my code they have used C++ MAPI extensively, So I doubt if OOM will help.